# Pokemon go account reset with no reason!

Tags: pokemon-go

I was trying to play this morning, when I open Pokemon go app, it ask me to confirm my gmail account so I ask to receive 6 number pin on my mobile by message. As soon as I confirmed it, it start from 0, chose your Pokemon,etc. what can I do to have back my account? I was already at level 15. I just use my mobile to play, I don't use any other device, and nobody else use my mobile. I didn't cheat. I start playing in London, I came to Madeira island in holiday's and I will be back to London in 6 days. Thank you very much for your attention.

I've tryed many things to fix it, but nothing. I try to start again choose the same name but it says not available. Does it mean I still have the chance to recover my account?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent Pokemon Go update made some users of Pokemon Go loose all their data. Here's the story. 
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/07/31/pokemon-go-fans-devastated-after-game-update-resets-their-progre/